# Solving a triangle in python

Tags: python, trigonometry

What math.function do I need to solve an AAS triangle?

[image: sample triangle]

Given measurement A and angles j and g (h is 90), I need to solve for C or B. Doesn't matter which, Pythagoras will take it from there.

I have looked up "solving AAS triangles" and using an online calculator (and estimates in my head) I know what the numbers should be plus or minus, but I'm not even coming close to that answer in my python code. I'm pretty sure I'm just using the wrong function for my calculation.

Comment: Please post the relevant code you have till now.

Comment: I think math.sin and math.cos etc want radians.

Comment: What code have you tried? What results are you getting? I suspect this is a radians vs. degrees issue, but without code, I have no idea.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: More suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MorganThrapp youre on a rampage today with those comments

Comment: @heinst It's a slow day at work today. Lots of "run this thing for half an hour and see where it errors out".

Comment: B = 6 * math.sin(29) / math.sin(90)
- or -    
B = A * math.sin(j) / math.sin(f) ... where 29 and 90 are degrees.

Comment: This isn't a math question, btw. I know the forumla, I just can't make it work in python.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen You dropped the hint I needed. It is a radians vs. degrees issue. When I introduced math.radians into the equation, it worked a treat.  -- B = A * math.sin(math.radians(j)) / math.sin(math.radians(f))

Comment: Bill if you've solved your problem then answer your own question so future users can get some use out of it.

Comment: I did, in my comment. There's quite a lot of etiquette I'm still learning apparently.

Answer (score 0):

@NightShadeQueen You dropped the hint I needed. It is a radians vs. degrees issue. When I introduced math.radians into the equation, it worked a treat. -- B = A * math.sin(math.radians(j)) / math.sin(math.radians(f))